# Evaluate dynamic mathmatical functions

Tags: r

Say I have the below terms and operators

```
x <- 0
y <- '<'
z <- 1
```

and I have constructed this into a string:

```
paste(x, y, z)   # "0 < 1"
```

How do I then get R to evaluate this string to give `TRUE`?
I have tried `eval` which returns a character
tried `parse` which gives `cannot open the connection`

Thank you.

Comment: `do.call(y, list(x, z))` or if you must evaluate a string as an expression then `eval(str2expression(paste(x, y, z)))`.

Comment: Yes, both work. Thanks for alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `eval` and `parse` with text like this:

```r
x <- 0
y <- '<'
z <- 1
eval(parse(text = paste(x,y,z)))
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I see. I was missing the argument `text` then needed the result to be evaluated. Thank you, Quinten